# Ajax HTTP request fetching result from wrong Flask endpoint

Tags: html, ajax, flask

I'm building a chatbot, and my Jquery ajax() method's HTTP request fetches data from the wrong endpoint.

This is the JS:

```
$.ajax({
     data: {
        msg: rawText,
        policy: rawPolicy,
        subpolicy: rawSubPolicy
     },
     url: "/get",
     method: "POST",
     success: function(response){
     $("#chatArea").prepend($.parseHTML(response));
}});
```

The Flask/Python:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/get",methods=["GET","POST"])
def chat():
    msg = request.form["msg"]
    policy = request.form["policy"]
    subpolicy = request.form["subpolicy"]

    input = msg

    if policy == "daod" or policy == "qrao":
        subpolicy = "/" + subpolicy

    df = fetch_db(policy,subpolicy)

    return ask(input,df)

def fetch_db(filecode,subfilecode):
```

**So it looks like the ajax call is accessing the "/" endpoint, because the response from the chatbot ends up simply being the html code for index.html.**

My .htaccess looks as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [L]

DirectoryIndex templates/index.html
```

If I remove this code for the .htaccess, I get 404 errors when the ajax call is made.

Comment: I would start flask in debug mode to determine if the jquery method calls the `/get` endpoint or not.

Comment: Yep everything works correctly when I run my app locally, but the problem arises when I deploy my webapp to a hosting server. This is the terminal output: 127.0.0.1 -  "POST /get HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: Using the network tab in my browser's console, I can see that the url/get is accessed, but for some reason, the Flask code returns index.html instead of the output of the chat() function above.

Comment: hard to believe the flask is sending the output of another route. you can add some debugging statement in the `/` route to see if indeed is getting triggered.

Comment: So it looks like the issue was the third line in the .htaccess file, where everything was being rewritten to the "/" route. I removed it, but now every ajax call returns a 404 error saying that "url/get" doesn't exist.